# SQL Server : search inside single quote

Tags: sql, t-sql, full-text-search

I have `Table1` in SQL Server like this:

```
ID | Name
---+--------------
1  | Robert Bart
2  | Andy Wor
3  | Sam O'Neil
4  | Bill Neil
```

Full text is enabled and my T-SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE CONTAINS([Name], @Keywords)
```

The parameter `@Keywords` is of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

My problem is, when `@Keyword` is Neil I only get record #4 as result; is there a way to get the records #3 and #4 from a select passing `Neil` as `@Keywords`?

I'm using MS SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have a hard time to customize Microsoft's FTS.
Word breakers change with every version of SQL Server and depend on the language you used to create the fulltext index.
You might be able to find a default language that splits O'Neil to O + Neil, but i wouldn't count on that.
More info on setting locale identifiers: [CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX with a LCID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-creating-a-full-text-index-on-several-table-columns)

If you really want to customize the word breakers, you have 2 options:

1. [Create a custom dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/customize-the-behavior-of-word-breakers-with-a-custom-dictionary?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. [Write a Language Resource DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/implementing-a-word-breaker-and-stemmer?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Easiest workaround would be to split the names by delimiters, like quotes, before inserting them to Table1 like `REPLACE(Name, '''', ' ')`
If you need the original full name, just store that in a different column/table.

Answer (score 0):

If someone need it, I've found a workaround; I've set my fulltextindex on the column table Table1.Name the Language for Word Breaker set to French instead of English.
This will search in the Name without O'